# Not able to read messages from SQS using @SqsListener

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to develop a SQS Listener which runs in background and reads message from AWS SQS whenever a new message arrives and it should never delete the message, since there will be a separate process for deleting message.

This is a standalone application, just started developing. But not able to proceed further since the basic thing is not working. I'm sure I'm missing something. I am using **spring-cloud-aws-messaging (version: 1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT).**

It's a very simple standalone application, having below files:
**One spring config file: application-context.xml (content already pasted above)
One SQS Listener: SBSQSMessageListener (content already pasted above)
One main program which is loading the application-context.xml & creating ApplicationContext**

**My Spring config file:**

```
<aws-context:context-region region="us-west-2"/>

<aws-context:context-credentials>
    <aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="xxxxxxx" secret-key="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
</aws-context:context-credentials>

<aws-messaging:queue-messaging-template id="queueMessagingTemplate" />      

<aws-messaging:annotation-driven-queue-listener task-executor="simpleTaskExecutor" />           

<bean id="simpleTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="4" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="1" />
    <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
</bean>
```

My SQSListener:

```
package sb.aws.sqs.listener;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.config.annotation.EnableSqs;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.annotation.SqsListener;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.Acknowledgment;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SqsMessageDeletionPolicy;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@EnableSqs
public class SBSQSMessageListener {

final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SBSQSMessageListener.class);  

@MessageMapping("sb-sqs-queue1")    
@SqsListener(value = "sb-sqs-queue1", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER)    
public void receive(String message, Acknowledgment acknowledgment)  {

    System.out.println("Inside receive: " + message);       

    try {
        acknowledgment.acknowledge().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I'm getting below exception:

> DT:02/17/2017 15:20:20 LL:DEBUG hostname: storeId: txnId:
>   CL:DefaultListableBeanFactory MSG:Creating shared instance of
>   singleton bean 'simpleMessageListenerContainer' DT:02/17/2017 15:20:20
>   LL:DEBUG hostname: storeId: txnId: CL:DefaultListableBeanFactory
>   MSG:Creating instance of bean 'simpleMessageListenerContainer'
>   DT:02/17/2017 15:20:20 LL:DEBUG hostname: storeId: txnId:
>   CL:DefaultListableBeanFactory MSG:Returning cached instance of
>   singleton bean
>   'org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.config.annotation.SqsConfiguration'
>   DT:02/17/2017 15:20:20 LL:DEBUG hostname: storeId: txnId:
>   CL:DefaultListableBeanFactory MSG:Returning cached instance of
>   singleton bean 'amazonSQSAsync' DT:02/17/2017 15:20:20 LL:DEBUG
>   hostname: storeId: txnId: CL:DefaultListableBeanFactory MSG:Creating
>   shared instance of singleton bean 'amazonSQS' DT:02/17/2017 15:20:20
>   LL:DEBUG hostname: storeId: txnId: CL:DefaultListableBeanFactory
>   MSG:Creating instance of bean 'amazonSQS' DT:02/17/2017 15:20:20
>   LL:DEBUG hostname: storeId: txnId: CL:DefaultListableBeanFactory
>   MSG:Returning cached instance of singleton bean
>   'org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.config.annotation.SqsClientConfiguration'
>   DT:02/17/2017 15:20:21 LL:DEBUG hostname: storeId: txnId:
>   CL:DefaultListableBeanFactory MSG:Eagerly caching bean 'amazonSQS' to
>   allow for resolving potential circular references DT:02/17/2017
>   15:20:21 LL:DEBUG hostname: storeId: txnId:
>   CL:DefaultListableBeanFactory MSG:Finished creating instance of bean
>   'amazonSQS' Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'simpleMessageListenerContainer' defined
>   in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/config/annotation/SqsConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type [com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync]: : No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync] is
>   defined: expected single matching bean but found 2:
>   amazonSQSAsync,amazonSQS; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync] is
>   defined: expected single matching bean but found 2:
>   amazonSQSAsync,amazonSQS  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>     at sb.aws.sqs.SBSQSMain.main(SBSQSMain.java:14)
>   **Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync] is
>   defined: expected single matching bean but found 2:
>   amazonSQSAsync,amazonSQS**    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
>     ... 15 more

Please could you guide me if I'm missing anything?

Many Thanks.

Comment: @Alain - Hi Alain, would be great if you could help me here. Thanks!

Comment: Somehow able to get rid off the exceptions and Listener is working, but now the problem is - SQSListener log keeps on rolling very very fast even if there is no new message in SQS Queue. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can set the `wait-time-out` attribute to a value between 1 and 20 on the `annotation-driven-queue-listener` element. For the details, you can read this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html

Comment: Thanks Alain. Yes, I had tried this already. Although it works better, but I was thinking if there is a way to invoke the listeners only when a new message is received in SQS. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, how did you solved this problem ?