# AWS SQS : All messages are getting picked at once and moved to in-flight However I want them to be processed one by one

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have created an SQS consumer which is supposed to pick a single message at once, process(takes 20 minute on an avg) it and then acknowledge. However what it is doing is, it picks all the messages(available in queue) at once and move them in flight(most annoying part) and then it process one by one but the last message would still remain in flight till visibility timeout expires (though all other messages would have processed).

I have tried giving a timeout in receive but that didn't work. I am using the below code to poll the queue and process the messages accordingly

```
public void startReceiving(String sqsServiceUrl, String queueName) throws JMSException {
            String msgAsString = StringUtils.EMPTY;
            do {
                tryToReconnect(sqsServiceUrl, queueName);
                msgAsString = receiveMessage(getMessageConsumer(sqsServiceUrl, queueName));     
            } while(!StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(msgAsString, "exit"));
        }

    private String receiveMessage(MessageConsumer consumer) throws JMSException {
            Message message = consumer.receive(0);  
            String msgAsString = StringUtils.EMPTY;     
            } else {
                try {
                    msgAsString = ((SQSTextMessage) message).getText();
                    /*Do some processing and overwrite msgAsString value with returned one*/
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                }
                finally{
                    message.acknowledge();
                }       
            }           
            return msgAsString;
        }

    private void tryToReconnect(String sqsServiceUrl, String queueName) throws JMSException {
            String currentHour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);    
            if (!savedHour.equals(currentHour) || (session  == null  || messageConsumer == null)){
                synchronized(lock){
                    if (messageConsumer == null){
                        savedHour = currentHour;
                        SQSConnection connection = createSqsConnection(sqsServiceUrl, queueName);
                        session = createSqsSession(connection);
                        messageConsumer = createMessageReciever(connection, queueName); 
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
```

I am polling the queue with the help of infinite loop, I want the code in such a way so that it picks one message at a time from queue, process it, acknowledge it and then ONLY pick the next available one.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use `SqsListener`? You can apply similar strategy as in this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160399/not-able-to-read-messages-from-sqs-using-sqslistener).

Comment: You've got a while loop that continues *forever* until it gets a particular message.  The behavior you're describing is exactly what I expect - pull every message, don't delete it and then each message will be in-flight until it times out.

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi: There is no specific reason, I just wanted to have more control over each iteration.

Comment: @stdunbar: Though the loop runs forever, The real question is Why does it pick all messages at once. Even in while loop for each message it should at least take 20 minutes (avg processing time) and then pick another.